# suppress summary from salt-call but show warnings and errors

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to suppress all output from salt-call/salt state.apply unless there is an error or warning of any kind; no output means *no summary, either*.

No combination of  --state-verbose or  --state-output silences the summary.

Adding --out=quiet gets rid of the summary but also warnings and errors, providing only a return code.

For now, I am handling it this way:

```
salt-call state.apply <my_state> --state_output=mixed --state_verbose=false --out-file=/tmp/state-out-tmp-$$.txt
(($?)) && cat /tmp/state-out-tmp-$$.txt
rm /tmp/state-out-tmp-$$.txt
```

... but this seems to be overkill.

Is there some combination of options I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to output json and pipe it through an additional parsing step:

```bash
salt-call state.apply <my_state> --out=json | jq '.local[] | select(.result == false)'
```

A cleaner way is to [implement your own outputter](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/development/modules/) that returns exactly what you want to see:

```py
import json

def output(data, **kwargs):
    failing = {host: {state: ret["comment"] for state, ret in r.items() 
                      if ret["result"] is False} 
               for host, r in data.items()}
    return json.dumps(failing, indent=4)
```

Note that errors and warnings should also be logged, so you could simply go for:

```bash
salt-call state.apply <my_state> --out=quiet --log-level=warning
```